# Sentimental Analysis using Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am new to Machine Learning and NLP space. My requirement is to convert audio calls to text for Sentimental analysis.

**Flow :-**

1) Audio files -->> Text (using Speech recognitions API )

2) Perform Sentimental analysis of the output text

Since having a strong background on Java, thought of using Stanford CoreNLP. But, fine to use tensorflow or others if they have good benefits than CoreNLP.

Exposing a rest service which takes text( complete conversation ) as an input for sentimental analysis. Using CoreNLP for sentimental analysis. Not getting results as expected.
Not sure how to train this for my needs? Is it possible to train at run time with different context and the result should be based on the context and customers?

Is there any other better API for Sentimental analysis of a chat?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would have chosen python's NLTK sentiment analysis:

[NLTK's sentiment analysis](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sentiment.html)

and you can find an example here:
[example](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html)